# Using regex for the first time

Tags: javascript, regex

I just started using regex and I'm trying to solve this problem, but it keeps return null. What is wrong with my code?
I want it to return this = (833) 741-2093

```
function phoneNumber(numbers){
  var num = numbers.join('');
  var r = /\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}\-\d{4}/;
  var match = num.match(r);
  return match;
}

var output = phoneNumber([8, 3, 3, 7, 4, 1, 2, 0, 9, 3]);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Without jumping to the regex part, your var `num` doesn't even have the format (xxx) xxx-xxxx you want, and `.match()` doesn't give format to your string.

Comment: your regex has parentheses and hyphen in it.

Comment: Is there a method that would format that num? Newbie here!

Comment: Also, I think you are approaching the problem incorrectly. If you have array of 10 numbers that you need in phone number format, you can directly format it rather than formatting it someway and applying regex on it.

Comment: `8337412093` does not match `/\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}\-\d{4}/`. It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
function phoneNumber (numbers) {
  var numberStr = numbers.join('');
  return numberStr.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "\($1\) $2\-$3");
}

var output = phoneNumber([8, 3, 3, 7, 4, 1, 2, 0, 9, 3]);

console.log(output);
```

You need to capture the three sets of numbers first, and then format them in the second parameter of `.replace()`. [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/sItEZ0/1)

Comment: You're welcome @LukasLukeStateczny If my answer helped you could you please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: I'm deeply confused. Why would I paste the numbers together, then use a regexp to find parts of the resulting string, then reformat using `replace`, instead of just formatting the input directly?

Comment: Yes, you could use a regular JS concatenation to format the `numbers` array (e.g. `'(' + numbers[0] + numbers[1] + numbers[2] + ')'` etc.) but the OP did ask for a solution using regex @torazaburo

Comment: He clearly does not even know what regexp is or how to use it, much less if or how it might be a solution to his problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining `[8, 3, 3, 7, 4, 1, 2, 0, 9, 3]` to `"8337412093"` and then searching for "(###) ###-####" in that string (where # are numbers). Obviously, 8337412093 does not contain (833) 741-2093 so it can't be matched.

This is probably easier to do with sub-strings, but you could match the number in 3 groups and then reformat it using back references like in david's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44345871/6893866)

Answer (score 0):

Regexp is used for parsing and analyzing strings, not for formatting them. In your case, you are trying to format a list of numbers. Make a tiny template-like language:

```js
function format(template, digits) {
  let n = 0;
  return template.replace(/#/g, _ => digits[n++]);
}

console.log(format("(###) ###-####", [8, 3, 3, 7, 4, 1, 2, 0, 9, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here you go…

```js
function phoneNumber(numbers){
  var num = numbers.join('');
  var r = /^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/;
  return num.replace(r,'($1) $2-$3');
}

var output = phoneNumber([8, 3, 3, 7, 4, 1, 2, 0, 9, 3]);

console.log(output);
```